# Limit the range of least square regression

Tags: matlab, regression, least-squares

I wanted to do a regression on a set of data `A(k1,k2)`, however I wanted limit it regression within a range of `-K1<k1<K1` and `-K2<k<K2`. `A` is an image phase consist of `60x60` matrix, with dimension of `MxN`. Least squares approximation to be done by 0.1N/2 from the center of normalized frequency area of `A`.

Here's the portion of the code:

```
A=rand(60);
[m, n]=size(A);
[M,N] = meshgrid(1:m,1:n);
X = [M(:), N(:)];
B=regress(A(:), X);  %regression will be done on all the values of A, part where adjustment needed
hat=reshape(X*B,m,n);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first select the subset of your matrix on which you want to perform the regression:

```
% generate the full image
A_full=rand(60);
[m, n]=size(A_full);

% select the part you want, 
% it is not very clear to me if this is really the part you want, 
% but I think you will be able to change it to your needs
A=A_full(floor(m/2-0.1*m/2):ceil(m/2+0.1*m/2), floor(n/2-0.1*n/2):ceil(n/2+0.1*n/2)); 

% perform the regression on the selected part of A (like you did it)
[m, n]=size(A);
[M,N] = meshgrid(1:m,1:n);
X = [M(:), N(:)];
B=regress(A(:), X);  %regression will be done on all the values of A, part where adjustment needed
hat=reshape(X*B,m,n);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it possible to let all `k2` values zeros while maintaining all `k1` values, `A(k1,0)` ?

Comment: Yes, just define `A` as `A=A_full(floor(m/2-0.1*m/2):ceil(m/2+0.1*m/2),floor(n/2));` I assume `k2=0` corresponds with the middle of the matrix, which may not be the case. (index 0 doesn't exist in matlab)